# CORS issue while making an Ajax request for oauth2 access token

Tags: ajax, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, cors

I am making an ajax call from my client to the google oauth 2 API `'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http://blah.com&response_type=token&client_id....'` to get the access token, but i get following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://blah-blah.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access

I want the call to be ajax so that the user is not disturbed when the call is made through `url` or `window.location.href` or in other words, how can i get the access token such that the whole page does not load, and is it possible to resolve the above error???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OAuth2 auth endpoint doesn't support AJAX by design. It's an entry point to the authentication system, so you must get there by redirect. The result of the authentication is again a redirect to the URL you provide, so AJAX doesn't make much sense there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Ján Halasa. I'm just wondering: if my front-end is a SPA (e.g., Angular). How can I send back a JWT token after he has authenticated using Google, since it is now a redirect rather than a plain `get` request call where a client can obtain data directly back.

Comment: @Moody have you solved this question regarding sending back the JWT on a SPA?

Comment: @LuisMendes535 With OAuth2 questions it's good specify a full context - what flow/grant you want to use (code, implicit, hybrid) and what token (access, ID, refresh) you want to use for what purpose. JWT is just a format. I would suggest you to take a look at the [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-04) document, which will probably answer your questions.

Comment: @LuisMendes535 Yes - Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887018/angular-express-passport-authenticating-with-google-no-access-control-allow

Comment: I've been struggling SO hard with this, this lead me in the right direction. Thanks!