# Angular/Express/Passport - Authenticating with Google: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angular, express, oauth, cors, passport.js

**Context**

I am building a *stateless* application using Angular, Express & PassportJS and want to authenticate users using their Google account. After authenticating a user, my goal is to use JWT tokens to be able to have a stateless application.

**Angular 2 side**

Upon clicking the Google sign in button, the following code gets executed in my service:

```
login() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/google');
}
```

**Express side**

On express, the following gets executed:

```
// This gets executed first after clicking the sign in using Google button.
router.get('/api/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    session: false,
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
}));

// Google sends me back here (callback).
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: 'omitted',
        clientSecret: 'omitted',
        callbackURL: '/api/auth/google/callback'
    }, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {

        // Here, I obtain the profile and create a JWT token which I send back to the user.
        let jwtToken = generateToken(); // Code omitted for simplicity.

        cb(null, jwtToken); // assume success
    }
));

// After creating a JWT token, this will get executed. 
router.get('/api/auth/google/callback', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('google', (err, jwtToken) => {
        res.status(201).json(jwtToken);
    })(req, res);
});
```

**Error:**

After clicking the 'sign in with Google' button (i.e. making the `get` request from Angular), I receive the following error:

`Failed to load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=(long_string_here): No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

**What I have tried**

I have seen similar issues on Angular and React applications and while there are answers (which I have tried), there has been no 'accepted answer' that actually solves this issue. I'm truly appalled why this is such a problem:

The strange part is: if I directly call `window.location.href =  http://localhost:3000/api/auth/google` instead of making a `get` request, it works fine. However, then the issue is that I am not able to obtain my JWT token as I am being redirected completely.

I have also tried to enabled CORS in many different ways in the backend and allowed all kinds of origins. This does not change anything.

An important note here is that my Angular application is running on port `4200` and my Express application on port `3000`. However, even if I compile my Angular project and put it in the public folder of Express and serve it, I still get the same CORS issues!

Comment: this is issue with angular , node checks the source of request and throws cors error i think

Answer (score 18, accepted):

call like this from login,

```
flogin(){
 window.open('/auth/facebook',"mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=800,height=800");
let listener = window.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
  //message will contain facebook user and details
});

}
```

in server,
i'm hoping you've passport facebook-stratagy working

```
  app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email'] }));


app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth/fail' }),
function(req, res) {
    var responseHTML = '<html><head><title>Main</title></head><body></body><script>res = %value%; window.opener.postMessage(res, "*");window.close();</script></html>'
    responseHTML = responseHTML.replace('%value%', JSON.stringify({
        user: req.user
    }));
    res.status(200).send(responseHTML);


});
```

Comment: You ROCK! Thanks so much! How did you figure this out?! This is exactly the way it should be done: directly calling `/auth/facebook`. I'm just curious: do I have to send back the HTML? Is there a bit of a cleaner way to do this (directly send the user object somehow?) Thank you again!