# oauth2 with google (angular and nestjs google strategy) cors error

Tags: angular, cors, nestjs, passport-google-oauth2

```
  @Get('google')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleAuth(@Req() req) {}

  @Get('redirect')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleAuthRedirect(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
  let data: any = await this.authService.googleLogin(req);
  res.redirect(process.env.FE_REDIRECT_URL + '?accessToken=' + data.accessToken)
  }
```

this is the nestjs auth controller apis, from angular when trying to access the api with

```
http://localhost:4000/auth/google
```

im getting

```
 Request URL: http://localhost:4000/auth/google
 Request Method: GET
 Status Code: 302 Found
 Remote Address: [::1]:4000
 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

i have enabled cors on Nestjs not sure what's the issue, pls help

Answer (score -1):

The confirmed answer in this question [Angular/Express/Passport - Authenticating with Google: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887018/angular-express-passport-authenticating-with-google-no-access-control-allow) fixed my issue. Basically had to open it in new window and then send response in html as shown in the answer.