# Angular request to google oAuth fails due to CORS policy

Tags: node.js, angular, cors, xmlhttprequest, google-oauth

I've set up an angular/nodejs(express) application with google authentication but whenever I request to google oauth through angular app it throws a cors error but if I request directly from browser it works as it should.

Backend is running on port 3000 and angular is running on 4200.

I'm using `cors` package to allow all cors requests in server.js:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// Allowing all cors requests
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
```

Passport config:

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        keys,
        (token, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            process.nextTick(() => {
                User.findOne({ email: email })
                    .then(user => {
                        if (user) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            });
        }
    )
);
```

This is the google authentication route:

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email'],
        session: false
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        // Create JWT payload
        const payload = {
            id: req.user.id,
            email: req.user.email
        };

        jwt.sign(payload, secret, expires, (err, token) => {
            res.json(token);
        });
    }
);
```

And here is angular request:

```
googleAuth() {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/auth/google').pipe(
        map(user => {
            if (user) {
                localStorage.setItem(
                    'currentUser',
                    JSON.stringify(user)
                );
            }

            return user;
        })
    );
}
```

Error in chrome console:

```
Failed to load "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code...": No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access
```

I've also authorized JavaScript origins in google developers console:
[origins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwxmr.png)

I'm pretty new to angular and nodejs and I have read all the similar questions but couldn't find a workaround to this problem.

Comment: Is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276462/cors-issue-while-making-an-ajax-request-for-oauth2-access-token/43276710#43276710) helpful?

Answer (score 1):

**Try out this method of directly calling the URL: ( Pardon if I missed something syntactically, but basically this is the idea )**

```
googleAuth(){
 window.open('/google',"mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=800,height=800");
let listener = window.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
  //message will contain google user and details
});

}
```

and in server you have passport strategy set I assume, Now

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email'],
        session: false } ))

router.get('/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/auth/fail' }),
function(req, res) {
    var responseHTML = '<html><head><title>Main</title></head><body></body><script>res = %value%; window.opener.postMessage(res, "*");window.close();</script></html>'
    responseHTML = responseHTML.replace('%value%', JSON.stringify({
        user: req.user
    }));
    res.status(200).send(responseHTML);


});
```