# How can I have jwt token from server(Node.js) without making ajax call from client (Vue)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, authentication, cross-domain, passport-google-oauth

I am trying to add google based authentication to my app. Here is what I am doing

1. using `passport-google-oauth20` module for passport google strategy on my express.js server side
2. I have create two endpoints, first `auth/google` and second `auth/google/callback` which is a callback url for google-Oauth
3. In the strategy definition I am trying to create a jwt token which I want to somehow send to client.
4. On the client side which is a vue app, I have added google sign-in button which redirects on click to my endpoint created in server,
5. After that, exchange of `accessTokens` and `scoped informations` happens in the server side (where I am generating a jwt token as well). But I am wondering how can I get the access token back to the client after the authentication is successful on the server.

Note that I can't make an ajax call as it will raise `cors` issue. Any suggestions are highly appreciated ;

Answer (score 0):

can you please elaborate in detail, is the back-end node server in your control, because if it is then you should be able to set the CORS policy for your front-end application.

Comment: hey, I have control to the node server, but the problem here is that the OAuth2 auth doesn't support ajax call. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276462/cors-issue-while-making-an-ajax-request-for-oauth2-access-token .

Comment: If you are using an OAuth2 means you are already relying on some API for authentication then why do you want it to return a JWT Token? because by default the OAuth2 should return an access token